# parsing CSV file in Java with skipping the next row if is the first field is empty

Tags: java, parsing

I am using Java, and I have a CSV file that consists of 10 column and 5 rows. I would like to parse it into another CSV file with the this condition. if the first cell from any row is empty, skip that row, and jump to the next and so on. My code only reads all the rows and prints them, I want to have that condition and write into another CSV file.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CSV {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String x;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("Book1.csv"));
    scanner.useDelimiter(",");
    while(scanner.hasNext()){

            System.out.print(scanner.next());

    }
    scanner.close();
}
```

}

Example:

see the attached image please.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of delimiting the whole file, delimit line by line:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String x;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("Book1.csv"));
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()){                // If there is another line in the file
        x = scanner.nextLine();                  // Extract that line
        String[] values = x.split(",");          // Split that line at the commas
        if (!values[0].equals("")) {             // If the first value is not equal to empty
            System.out.print(x);                 // Print the line
        }
    }
    scanner.close();
}
```

Comment: I just tried this code, it actually only reads the first line, and skips all the other lines ??

Comment: Reads or prints the first line?  Also, forgot that strings in Java are not compared with == or != and use the .equals method. Could you try the updated code again?

Comment: just tried it again. it works partly. It ignores all the rows that starts with empty field but when it reaches the first row which its first field isn't empty, it prints it and stops??

Comment: Could you put a print statement to see how many times the loop is running?  I think your file has some weird return at the end of each line that is throwing off the scanner.

Comment: it goes over all the rows. it loops 5 times as many as the rows

Comment: Check your file and make sure that those rows don't start with a " " or some other control character and are in fact empty.  Or, you could remove whitespace from values[0] before checking if it equals ""

Comment: I just found out the problem. It actually works perfectly, but it was printing them all in the same line which I did not realize. Thank you.

Comment: ohhh haha!  That was a copy paste from your code :p

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the fact that each record is a different line. So, instead of using `Scanner` class directly over the `File`, you can retrieve full lines with [`BufferedReader#readLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()):

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Book1.csv"));
String myLine = br.readLine();
while (myLine != null) {
    // do whatever you want with the line

    // read new line
    myLine = br.readLine();
}
```

So that `myLine` contains Strings like the following:

```
"John,M,Mi,1111,US,OR,..."
",David,criss,2222,US,MI,..."
```

Once you have a line, [`trim()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--) it and check if the first character is your delimiter. In that case, the line should be ignored.

```
myLine = myLine.trim();
if (",".equals(myLine.at(0))) {
    // First field empty. Ignore
} else {
    // First field not empty. Write to new file
}
```

Comment: would you please provide an example code as I am new to java

Comment: Added. You will need to check things as empty lines, but it is basically this. However, don't forget that the purpose of answers is not to provide fully functional code, but to point how to write it :-)